# Detecting real vs "fake" browser wheel events in macOS

Tags: javascript, macos, signal-processing

Background: macOS generates synthetic "wheel" events when swiping the trackpad on websites. This is to simulate the behavior of a physical spinning mouse wheel. For my application, I need to know, probabilistically or otherwise, whether a given event is user-initiated or synthetic. There is no web api to do this, so I need to do some signal processing.

Below is a plot of mouse "wheel" events, where the x-axis is time and the y-axis is velocity. As you can see, regions where the user initiates a gesture generate a clear velocity spike, followed by a noisy polynomial decay in velocity. Since this decay is noisy, it is quite difficult to tell whether an event corresponds to a new interaction, or a synthetic OS event.

[image]

How can I analyze this data to determine whether the event was user-initiated or synthetic?

Comment: What's your use case? Is this just a curiosity thing? An analytics thing? Or are you actually trying to build a different experience on mouse via trackpad - because if it's the latter - that's really bad UX. Users assume trackpads will work in a particular way that is interchangeable with traditional mice.

Comment: Pretty good question nevertheless

Comment: @KonradLinkowski oh yeah, it's a fascinating problem, and I look forward to a solution. It's just also a red flag that someone is building a feature that is not accessible or intuitive. When the Browser doesn't supply an API to do something, it's often a sign that doing that this is ill advised.

Comment: Simple, it was all synthetic. The trackpad doesn't have a real wheel to roll, and even Apple's (relatively recent) mice don't either. So they're all synthetic. Now, as an avid user of this swipe-scroll feature, I do expect the smooth feedback to be there and I consider it part of my scrilling behavior just as much as when my fingers are actually touching the touch surface. So whatever you are trying to do, don't break my mouse please.

Comment: @NickBailey fear not - it's for a very high-end design site. The use-case is a paging carousel, where you can only move 1 page at a time. So once you hit a certain velocity, the carousel should page, but just 1 page. At that point, all scroll events should be ignored until the user starts scrolling again. A timeout can be used to prevent the extra scroll events, but that prevents the user from paging the carousel rapidly. A user would expect trackpad scrolling to work for navigating the carousel, but does not expect inertial scrolling.

Comment: Cool that makes sense. That is a really cool problem then :). Sorry to doubt you, I just see a lot of folks propose crazy stuff.

Comment: Please edit your question with this specific requirements then. You are in an XY problem. There are solutions designed specifically for this case, no need to break anything nor hack around: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue for years. For game controllers or better carousels it would be great to have access to whether or not a wheel event was dispatched by the user touching their mouse or trackpad, vs the system automatically generating it.

The best solution would be to wait for Mac or W3C to have the browser attach that data but I don't believe that will happen any time soon but I do think you were on to something with your graph. Today, we can use machine learning to predict whether the event is real or fake.

See my response to this issue for more information:
https://github.com/w3c/uievents/issues/58